# Why is this rule trying to redirect to a filesystem path instead of url?

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I've got a strange case. I just want to redirect all my old .html pages to same .php pages. but the code I think should work, won't work because it'll end up redirecting to full filesystem path instead of url, thus getting a 404.

the starting url is of this kind

```
dev.example.com/site-dir/my-page.html
```

or (local, same result)

```
http://localhost:5757/site-dir/my-page.html
```

the current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [R=301]
```

This will output a 404:

```
The requested URL /Users/[my user]/Documents/[my dirs]/my-page.php was not found on this server.
```

Why?

I'm currently using local apache, via MAMP PRO.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had to add the base directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-base-dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ $1.php [R=301,L] ### all x.html to x.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ $1.php [L] ### all paths without extensions to .php (pretty urls)
```